# React Native StackNavigator Adding image to header

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

Sorry about this but I am new to rect native and trying to add a image to the StackNavigator header. I have the following code

```
navigationOptions: { 
headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
header: (props) => <ImageHeader {...props} />,
headerStyle: styles.header
```

}

The ImageHeader component

```
const ImageHeader = props => (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }}>
        <Image
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }}
        />
        <Header {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}/>
      </View>
    );

export default class ImageTestHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  static defaultProps = { show: true }

  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.string,
    style: PropTypes.object,
    show: PropTypes.bool
  }

  render () {
    <ImageHeader />

  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error when I run the app.

[image]

Can some one please explain what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are exporting `ImageTestHeader` and using `ImageHeader` as your header component. export `ImageHeader` too or use `ImageTestHeader`

Answer (score 0):

in your render you should return the component or null

```
render() {
  return (<ImageHeader />);
}
```